# Get value from JavaScript of a cell of a dynamic table (VisualforcePage)

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce

I am creating a DYNAMIC tables, and I want to call a JavaScript (by clicking) function getting the value of a determinate cell. The problem is that I am trying to get the value using an **input hidden**, and this is always getting the first value of the first table.

How can I get the value of the determinate cell.

My code is the next one:

```
 <apex: repeat ....>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!block}" var="document" id="docList">
        <apex:column headerValue="NameHeader">
            <apex:commandLink value="{!document.Nombre_doc_adjuntos__c}" id="checkfunction" onclick="jsFunction();" >
                <input type="hidden" class="DocClass" id="AttDocClass" name="AttDocClass" value="{!document.id}" />
            </apex:commandLink>                             
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:repeat>
```

So how can I get the value of my dynamics table, not to get the first value of the first table?

Cheers

Comment: put your code what you tried , and possible dublicate ID.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to read the value and populate the hidden input field.